# How to give path as a parameter in callproc function of cx_Oracle

Tags: python, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a procedure that creates a csv file as the output. I am trying to call that procedure using callproc(). The procedure takes path as an input. How do I give that input using callproc() function?

Comment: That's covered in the [official docs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html)

Comment: Just wondering: that's an Oracle stored procedure, right? How exactly does it create a CSV file? If it is by using the UTL_FILE package, then it is more or less *useless* to pass a path because target directory is determined by Oracle directory object you're "allowed" to use (i.e. you're being granted required privileges), and I - somehow - doubt that DBA created "many" directories you could use.